# Recursively calling a class (Implementing linked list)

Tags: oop, matlab, data-structures, linked-list

Hi I am trying to implement a linked list in Matlab.

The implementation I am hoping to do is (this is the C equivalent):

```
class Node{
    public Node* child;
}
```

I have looked around but don't seem to get anything quite close.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd clarify the question a bit. (1) You say you're trying to implement a recursive method, but you don't say anything about what exactly you want it to do or what you've tried already. (2) You say "this is the C equivalent" but then follow it with something that is not C. (And that doesn't seem to involve any methods, recursive or otherwise.)

Comment: If what you're actually aiming to do is simply to make a class one of whose properties' value is a reference to another object of the same class ... then you don't need to do anything special at all. MATLAB classes' properties don't have types attached to them, and nothing is stopping you saying (e.g.) `x.child = x`. But you should probably say `class myclass < handle` so that you work with references rather than copies.

Comment: I am sorry to have been vague in my point. Though what I was looking around was a linked list implementation by OOP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you want to implement a linked list:

```
   classdef Node < handle
       properties
          Next = Node.empty(0); %Better than [] because it has same type as Node.
          Data;
       end         

       methods
           function this = Node(data)
               if ~exist('data','var') 
                  data = [];
               end
               this.Data = data;
           end
       end
   end
```

Creation :

```
   n1 = Node('Foo'); %Create one node
   n2 = Node('Bar'); %Create another one
   n1.Next = n2; %Link between them
```

Iteration:

```
   n = n1;
   while ~isempty(n)
       disp(n.Data);   %Change this line as you wish
       n = n.Next;           
   end
```